# How do you change schema in a Spark `DataFrame.map()` operation without joins?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In Spark v3.0.1 I have a DataFrame of arbitrary schema.

I want to turn that DataFrame of arbitrary schema into a new DataFrame with the same schema and a new column that is the result of a calculation over the data discretely present in each row.

I can safely assume that certain columns of certain types are available for the logical calculation despite the DataFrame being of arbitrary schema.

I have solved this previously by creating a new `Dataset[outcome]` of two columns:

- the KEY from the input DataFrame
- the OUTCOME of the calculation

... and then joining that DF back on the initial input to add the new column:

```scala
val inputDf = Seq(
  ("1", "input1", "input2"),
  ("2", "anotherInput1", "anotherInput2"),
).asDF("key", "logicalInput1", "logicalInput2")

case class outcome(key: String, outcome: String)

val outcomes = inputDf.map(row => {
  val input1 = row.getAs[String]("logicalInput1")
  val input2 = row.getAs[String]("logicalInput2")
  val key = row.getAs[String]("key")

  val result = if (input1 != "") input1 + input2 else input2
  outcome(key, result)
})

val finalDf = inputDf.join(outcomes, Seq("key"))
```

Is there a more efficient way to map a DataFrame to a new DataFrame with an extra column given arbitrary columns on the input DF upon which we can assume some columns exist to make the calculation?

I'd like to take the inputDF and map over each row, generating a copy of the row and adding a new column to it with the outcome result without having to join afterwards...

NOTE that in the example above, a simple solution exists using Spark API... My calculation is not as simple as concatenating strings together, so the `.map` or a udf is required for the solution. I'd like to avoid UDF if possible, though that could work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `withColumn` with an `UDF`. I don't see why `map` should be preferred, and I think it's very difficult to append a column in DataFrame API

Or you switch to Dataset API

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I suppose in this case, since all the data is available in the incoming dataFrame, that using a UDF would be ok... I know spark has issues with query planning around UDFs, but this UDF is only operating on data in the immediate dataframe, so should be performant, ya?

Answer (score 3):

Before answering exact question about using `.map` I think it is worth a brief discussion about using UDFs for this purpose. UDFs were mentioned in the "note" of the question but not in detail.

When we use `.map` (or `.filter`, `.flatMap`, and any other higher order function) on any `Dataset` [1] we are forcing Spark to fully deserialize the entire row into an object, transforming the object with a function, and then serializing the entire object again. This is very expensive.

A UDF is effectively a wrapper around a Scala function that routes values from certain columns to the arguments of the UDF. Therefore, Spark is aware of which columns are required by the UDF and which are not and thus we save a lot of serialization (and possibly IO) costs by ignoring columns that are not used by the UDF.

In addition, the query optimizer can't really help with `.map` but a UDF can be part of a larger plan that the optimizer will (in theory) minimize the cost of execution.

I believe that a UDF will usually be better in the kind of scenario put forth int the question. Another smell that indicate UDFs are a good solution is how little code is required compared to other solutions.

```scala
val outcome = udf { (input1: String, input2: String) =>
    if (input1 != "") input1 + input2 else input2
}  

inputDf.withColumn("outcome", outcome(col("logicalInput1"), col("logicalInput2")))
```

---

Now to answer the question about using `.map`! To avoid the join, we need to have the result of the `.map` be a `Row` that has all the contents of the input row with the output added. `Row` is effectively a sequence of values with type `Any`. Spark manipulates these values in a type-safe way by using the schema information from the dataset. If we create a new `Row` with a new schema, and provide `.map` with an `Encoder` for the new schema, Spark will know how to create a new `DataFrame` for us.

```scala
val newSchema = inputDf.schema.add("outcome", StringType)
val newEncoder = RowEncoder(newSchema)

inputDf
  .map { row =>
    val rowWithSchema = row.asInstanceOf[GenericRowWithSchema] // This cast might not always be possible!
    
    val input1 = row.getAs[String]("logicalInput1")
    val input2 = row.getAs[String]("logicalInput2")
    val key = row.getAs[String]("key")

    val result = if (input1 != "") input1 + input2 else input2
    
    new GenericRowWithSchema(rowWithSchema.toSeq.toArray :+ result, row.schema).asInstanceOf[Row] // Encoder is invariant so we have to cast again.
  }(newEncoder)
  .show()
```

Not as elegant as the UDFs, but it works in this case. However, I'm not sure that this solution is universal.

---

[1] `DataFrame` is just an alias for `Dataset[Row]`

Comment: Great explanation and solution using the generic row, thanks.